# Flutter mapbox polyline maps

Tags: flutter, dart, mapbox, fluttermap

I am trying to create polyline map using mapbox, which I am able to create properly.
User can come back and can see see polyline maps in his profile.

Doubt - Is there any way I can convert my list of lat long into some format and store in db and later on we fetch it from db and render map?

I checked geojson format also but if we use geoJson with mapbox it generates static maps.

I am using flutter_map to generate maps.

Updated -

```
var geoJson =   {
              "type": "polyline",
              "coordinates": [
                [
                  76.61219358444214,
                  27.555764420824236
                ],
                [
                  76.6120433807373,
                  27.55395717009122
                ],
                [
                  76.61094903945923,
                  27.55285378133631
                ],
                [
                  76.61021947860718,
                  27.55138892051556
                ],
                [
                  76.61000490188599,
                  27.550285505956428
                ],
                [
                  76.6101336479187,
                  27.549372326903264
                ],
                [
                  76.6107988357544,
                  27.548287916916344
                ],
                [
                  76.61150693893433,
                  27.547831320034653
                ],
                [
                  76.61109924316406,
                  27.54568148421033
                ],
                [
                  76.61097049713135,
                  27.54391211873852
                ]
              ]
            }
```

Currently I am using flutter_map package and using below code to render map.

```
var points =  [LatLng(latitude:27.591585, longitude:76.61139), LatLng(latitude:27.591548, longitude:76.611397), LatLng(latitude:27.591473, longitude:76.611407), LatLng(latitude:27.591437, longitude:76.611413), LatLng(latitude:27.591362, longitude:76.611425), LatLng(latitude:27.591325, longitude:76.61143), LatLng(latitude:27.59125, longitude:76.611442), LatLng(latitude:27.591177, longitude:76.611452), LatLng(latitude:27.59114, longitude:76.611458), LatLng(latitude:27.591065, longitude:76.61147), LatLng(latitude:27.591028, longitude:76.611475), LatLng(latitude:27.591007, longitude:76.611587), LatLng(latitude:27.591013, longitude:76.611693), LatLng(latitude:27.590777, longitude:76.611805), LatLng(latitude:27.590657, longitude:76.611822), LatLng(latitude:27.590535, longitude:76.61184), LatLng(latitude:27.590413, longitude:76.611857), LatLng(latitude:27.590293, longitude:76.611875), LatLng(latitude:27.590172, longitude:76.611892)]



return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text('Leaflet Maps')),
        body: new FlutterMap(
            options: new MapOptions(
                center:  new LatLng(27.563896, 76.600460), minZoom: 10.0),
            layers: [
              new TileLayerOptions(
                  urlTemplate:
             "https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/jainaman8/ckd5v8bs00zm01ir3w3bjrrb3/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}@2x?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN",
                  additionalOptions: {
                    'accessToken': '',
                    'id': 'mapbox.mapbox-streets-v8'
                  }
              ),

            new PolylineLayerOptions(
              polylines: [
                new Polyline(
                  points: points,
                  strokeWidth: 2.0,
                  color:  Colors.red
                )
              ]
            )
```

I want to store geoJson object into firebase and then pull this data from there and render map using mapbox.

I read on google that firebase does not support arrays so another doubt is that how can I store this data on firebase ?

Comment: Without seeing any code is hard to understand why geojson or any other custom json format is not an option. geojson supports Point, Line, Polygon and Multipolygon. Could you clarify what is the requirement or provide an insight in the objects you're rtying to persist?

Comment: @jscastro I have tried to add more description and code. Let me know if you still have doubt.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the desired by making a collection of field of type geopoint and then get those fields in your flutter project.